# Delphi closure and "old style" object type

Tags: delphi, closures

Working with anonymous functions I found out that sometimes the compiler throws the following error:
**E2555 Cannot capture symbol 'Self'** when I try to  use some field of the object. 
I also noticed that this error seems to be related to the fact that a type, the method belongs to, is declared with "object" key word:

```
MyType = object()
    field: integer;
...
end; 

MyType.Method1()
begin
    p := procedure
    begin
        // do something with field
    end;
end;
```

However when a type is declared with "class" keyword it seems it works fine.

I know that to prevent the compiler error I can make a local copy of needed fields and use them inside the anonymous functions, but just to be sure - is "object" type cause of the compiler error and what's the reason of that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm surprised you seem to expect Delphi closures to work with Turbo Pascal-style objects at all.  They were obsolete 20 years ago - why are you still using them?

Comment: Why would Emba have attempted to support this new feature on TP objects from last century? Why are you trying? That said. Even if they wanted to how could they? These are value types. Same issue arises with records I'll bet.

Comment: Because I forced to maintain a legacy code...

Comment: Then maintain it as legacy code, as if Delphi's class model never existed.

Comment: @MartynA : Yes maintain it as legacy code, but `object` types work just fine with the class model (just not as *part* of it, just as `record` types are not part of that class model either).  What `object` types may not work so well with (as in the OP's case) are closures, generics and other new language features.  *Those* are the things to be avoided in legacy code since that legacy code (not just involving `object` types) was never originally written to take account of the foibles and corner cases that the new language features suffer from/introduce.

Comment: @Deltics:  Maybe so.  My recollection of D1 is that the selling point of including support for TP objects was to ease the transition of existing codebases to Delphi classes.  Expecting TP objects to carry on working in the face of 21 years' worth of subsequent OP language developments just seems a bit foolhardy to me.

Comment: @MatrynA - they were deprecated and you couldn't have expected them to be maintained and updated to take advantage of/participate in new language features (rtti, interfaces etc etc), but never-the-less carried on working perfectly well as *originally* specified.   Just as the BDE carried on working long after it too was deprecated but wasn't maintained or updated to "play nice" with Vista et al (out of the box, but it could be done).

Comment: What do you want to do inside the anonymous method? It's easy to read the fields, I can show if its applicable to your problem.

Comment: All I wanted to find out is why it is not implemented - due to the fact that they (objects) are just deprecated and not supported by new language features or due to anything else.

Comment: I tested with a record, and it was as @DavidHeffernan predicted, same error as with object. So it seems that a value type is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Turbo Pascal `object` is long deprecated, it is reasonable for new language features not to have support for `object`.

There's not really any need to look much further. Since you are maintaining legacy code, I would not expect you to be introducing new language features like anonymous methods. Once you start introducing such language features, this no longer feels like legacy code maintenance and it would be reasonable to re-factor the code away from the legacy language features like `object`.

Having said that, I do note that the same restriction to capture applies in methods of advanced records.

```
type
  TProc = reference to procedure;
  TRecord = record
    procedure Foo;
  end;

procedure TRecord.Foo;
var
  P: TProc;
begin
  P :=
    procedure
    begin
      Foo;
    end;
end;
```

This fails to compile with error:

> E2555 Cannot capture symbol 'Self'

Why does this code fail, even though advanced records are a fully supported modern feature?

I don't have an explanation for that and the documentation does not make it clear. A plausible explanation is that records are value types. When a local variable is captured, it is hoisted from being a stack allocated variable to a variable owned by an internally created class. That's possible for `Self` when `Self` is a reference to an instance of a class. But when `Self` is a value like a record, it is too late to hoist the record.

Or perhaps it is much more prosaic. Maybe the designers just implemented the most important use case (capturing `Self` for a class) and omitted the less widely used cases for expediency. It is frustrating that the documentation does not appear to give any rules for what can and cannot be captured.

Comment: Declaring `P : TProc<PRecord>;`, where `PRecord` is a pointer to `TRecord` is a way to deal with it, and works for object too. `P := procedure(T: PRecord) begin T^.Foo; end;`

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thanks for the answer. I'm not going to introduce any new language features without related refactoring.
I just asked about the possible causes of this behavior (apart from the obvious - objects are just deprecated and not supported). Your penultimate paragraph is an interesting idea, thanks again.

Comment: @LU RD: Thanks for your investigation

Answer (score 4):

As David properly analyzed it is because `Self` in your case is a value and not a reference. It cannot be moved to the internally created class - same is the case with any method arguments that are records. They also cannot be captured for the very same reason.

For arguments I usually copy them to a local variable which is being captured.
The same can be done for capturing `Self` in a `record` or `object`.

However if you capture it as value you get a copy and calling the closure later might have the "wrong" state because it captured a copy. To make it work similar you would have to capture a reference to `Self` but then for a value type you cannot guarantee that this reference is still valid when you call the closure.

You can see this in the following code:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TProc = reference to procedure;
  PRecord = ^TRecord;
  TRecord = object
    y: Integer;
    procedure Foo;
    function GetProc: TProc;
  end;

procedure TRecord.Foo;
begin
  Writeln(y);
end;

function TRecord.GetProc: TProc;
var
  this: PRecord;
begin
  this := @Self;
  Result :=
    procedure
    begin
      this.Foo;
    end;
end;

procedure Nested(var p: TProc);
var
  r: TRecord;
begin
  p := r.GetProc();
  r.y := 0;
  p();
  r.y := 32;
  p();
end;

procedure Main;
var
  p: TProc;
begin
  Nested(p);
  p(); // <- wrong value because PRecord not valid anymore
end;

begin
  Main;
end.
```

If you would capture `TRecord` it would do a local copy that it captures - you can see that it then will print 0 all the time.